# Make API requests in Javascript using access_token

Tags: javascript, api, http, oauth, request

I have successfully gotten oAuth to work in my Phonegap application. As of now I can get the access_token using oAuth, but now I am stuck. How do I make API requests using this access_token? I am trying to access the Stripe API (https://stripe.com/docs/api).

I understand I need to sign the request, but how do I do that in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can add key=your_stripe_api_key_here to the request. For example,

```
https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers?key=your_stripe_api_key_here
```

Note: I am not sure how secure this method is.